# Namespace issue with Xpath xpression of loaded document with doc() on latest Saxon-10 jar

Tags: xml, xslt, jboss, java-11, saxon

Recently upgraded the Saxon-HE-9.7.0.8.jar to saxon-he-10.5.jar. Deploying the application in JBoss7 Server. refering to a set of urls in from xsl transformation as below :

```
<xsl:variable name="urls" select="document('urls.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name="cs"
      select="$urls/Bundle/entry/resource/CodeSystem[url/@value = $this]"/>
```

location of the xml file was relative and it is in same folder of XSL.

the content of the urls.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <entry>
    <resource>
      <CodeSystem>
        <url value="http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/"/>
        <identifier>
          <system value="urn:ietf:rfc:3986"/>
          <value value="urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.283"/>
        </identifier>
        <name value="COSMIC : Catalogue Of Somatic Mutations In Cancer"/>
      </CodeSystem>
    </resource>
  </entry>
</Bundle>
```

with saxon-9 jar, able to load and get the value in the variable in cs. with latest jar, after spending some time came across, when we give the xmlns attribute for child elements also then only we are getting the result into vairable "cs" as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Bundle xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
  <entry xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
    <resource xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
      <CodeSystem xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
        <url value="http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/"/>
        <identifier xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
          <system xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" value="urn:ietf:rfc:3986"/>
          <value xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" value="urn:oid:2.16.840.1.113883.6.283"/>
        </identifier>
        <name xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir" value="COSMIC : Catalogue Of Somatic Mutations In Cancer"/>
      </CodeSystem>
    </resource>
  </entry>
</Bundle>
```

any inputs will be helpful to avoid the namespace defintion for child elements in context of the latest saxon jar.

Comment: You can try a fully qualified path for the file

Comment: What does `doc-available('urls.xml')` give? Does JBoss allow you to see warnings or error messages Saxon might emit to the console or error listener?

Comment: yes, Jboss does provide error logs.  i will give a try.

Comment: What is the value of `static-base-uri()`? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @Michael Kay, it is default. not configured any value. we changed the jar file only

Comment: If `static-base-uri()` is not returning the actual URI of the stylesheet then the document() function isn't going to know where to find `urls.xml`. Perhaps in 9.7 static base URI defaulted to the current working directory? I seem to remember some APIs did that but we changed it partly to make all APIs consistent and partly because it's a dangerous default. How do you invoke the transformation?

Comment: doc-available('urls.xml') is giving value of true. tried with below stuff: ```<xsl:variable name="flag" select="doc-available('urls.xml')"/>```

Comment: And what does `count(doc('urls.xml'))` give? What kind of failure in your code do you see with Saxon HE 10 that didn't happen with 9.7?

Comment: @MartinHonnen, it is giving the value as 1 when i tried to put to one of result element attribute so it is able  to load the document? after debugging the same one more point i would to like to cross verify with you...we are applying the xpath on the result variable of loaded document ...could you help me out whether this is correct one ```<xsl:variable name="href" select="$url/entry[@value = $this]"/>``` am i doing correct here to get part of content dynamically. i am still able to see this same logic working on saxon 9.7 jar.

Comment: I don't follow, so the expression `count(doc('urls.xml'))` being `1` shows that Saxon loads a document. Test with e.g. `<xsl:copy-of select="$urls"/>` what the content is. If you need help writing XPath against the content or help explaining why your XPath fails we need to see some sample content including all namespaces declarations. Still kind of odd why Saxon 9.7 and 10 would differ but it seems the document is loaded in both.

Comment: copied the content of the loaded document with help <xsl:copy-of />...result is as below: <value xsi:type="CD" codeSystemName="" flagName="&#xA;  &#xA;    &#xA;      &#xA;        &#xA;        &#xA;          &#xA;          &#xA;        &#xA; ... many characters of &#xA;

Comment: Consider to edit the question and show relevant code samples there as formatted code snippets, then please explain and show what is failing in Saxon 10 that worked in Saxon 9.7 as currently it seems that the `doc` or `document` not working description no longer applies.